# 'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this LINQ query:

```
var gbaJoinTasksAndBatches = from gbajoin in _db.GBatchAudit
                                     join task1 in _db.TTask on gbajoin.TaskId equals task1.TaskId
                                     join batch1 in _db.TBatch on gbajoin.BatchId equals batch1.BatchId
                                     where gbajoin.EntryTime >= ReporterArgs.FromDate &&
                                           gbajoin.EntryTime <= ReporterArgs.ToDate &&
                                           gbajoin.EntryType == 1
                                     orderby gbajoin.EntryTime
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         gbajoin.EntryTime,
                                         gbajoin.BatchRunNum,
                                         task1.TaskId,
                                         task1.TaskName,
                                         batch1.BatchId,
                                         batch1.BatchName
                                     };

        var gbaGroupedByErrorMessage = from gbaJoin in gbaJoinTasksAndBatches
                                       group gbaJoin by new
                                       {
                                           gbaJoin.BatchRunNum,
                                           Task = gbaJoin.TaskName,
                                           TaskId = gbaJoin.TaskId,
                                           Batch = gbaJoin.BatchName,
                                           BatchId = gbaJoin.BatchId,
                                       } into taskBatchGroup

                                       select new TaskListDto
                                       {
                                           BatchName = taskBatchGroup.Key.Batch,
                                           BatchId = taskBatchGroup.Key.BatchId,
                                           TaskName = taskBatchGroup.Key.Task,
                                           TaskId = taskBatchGroup.Key.TaskId,
                                           BatchRunNumber = taskBatchGroup.Key.BatchRunNum,
                                           StartTime = taskBatchGroup.Min(grp => grp.EntryTime)
                                       };

        return await gbaGroupedByErrorMessage.OrderBy(t => t.StartTime).ToListAsync();
```

I keep getting an error "'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name."
but i really don't understand why. 
I assume it's somewhere in that line:

```
StartTime = taskBatchGroup.Min(grp => grp.EntryTime)
```

But i *do* want to get a grouping with the min datetime of that query.
Weird thing is, that it actually used to work till yesterday, before I update the .net packages to 2.1.0-preview2-final

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this is the risk of using pre-release builds. Go back to the official 2.0.2

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, good idea. Do you think they will get it working on the final 2.1.0 ? I mean, i know you can predict that, I just wonder if I'll have to stay with 2.0.2 forever

Comment: Definitely. Translating `GroupBy` with aggregates to server side (SQL) is one of the main items of 2.1. I see there is already a preview3, you could try and see if it's fixed. Also consider posting it to their issue tracker, so they know about it - might be a specific query construct they've missed in translation.

Comment: @IvanStoev I posted that issue, and they accepted it. thanks Ivan! https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11636